# Eclipse plugin highlighting word from specified symbol

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

How to highlight a word from specified symbol. For instance I printed `class$method` and should be highlighted `$method` part. I tried to use `SingleLineRule` class but unfortunately it didn't help me.

Comment: Maybe `WordPatternRule` but it isn't clear from your question what the problem is. Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I print the word CLASS$METHOD and should be highlighted $METHOD part. Is it clear?

Comment: Not it isn't clear. Show us code.

Comment: I don't have a code yet. I have only a sample http://prnt.sc/e1rpse. I don't have idea how to implement it